# How to update a TextField

Tags: java, field, jpanel, textfield

What I have is a Phase Plot, and a new trajectory can be drawn from entering the values x0 and y0 in a textfield. But I've made it possible to change x0 and y0 by clicking on the plot, the problem I'm having is that the new x0 and y0 aren't written out in the textfield, which is what I am trying to do, which I have had no luck with, so I'm turning to people who know this better than I do.

There is so much code, posting it all would be rather tedious. For me and for you to read through it all.

So I have this code:

```
  public static class NumberField extends Field {
    protected NumberFormat numberFormat;
    protected Number min;
    protected Number max;
    protected Number defValue;
    protected boolean strictMin;
    protected boolean strictMax;
//Here follows some constructors, don't know if I need to post them here
```

Here the problem arises

```
   protected enum OptionField {

        ...
            X(new NumberField("x₀", 1., 0., true)),
        Y(new NumberField("y₀", 1., 0., true)),
        ...

        final public NumberField field;
        OptionField(NumberField f){field = f;}
    }
```

And also: (OptionPanel is a JPanel)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Parameters p = new Parameters();
        p.plotType = e.getActionCommand();
        ...
        p.x0 = optionPanel.getNumber(OptionField.X.name()).doubleValue();
        p.y0 = optionPanel.getNumber(OptionField.Y.name()).doubleValue();
        ...

        }
```

I've tried (and realized it was rather stupid) just to replace the 1 inside the NumberField with the value that that I get from the click. But the compiler then tells me:

non-static variable x0 cannot be referenced from a static context

Help me please!

---

It complains when I try this:

This is the code that defines x0

```
private class Parameters {
String plotType;
String method;
double c, s, a, b, t1,  h0, h1, xFP, yFP, xB, yB, al;
double x0 = 1.;
double y0 = 1.;
```

and

```
plot.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(param.plotType == "PHASE_PLOT"){
        param.x0 = (((double) e.getX()-45)/680)*param.xB;
        param.y0 = -(((double) e.getY()-550)/510)*param.yB;
```

then I try to do this cos I have no idea what to do

```
protected enum OptionField {
    ...
    X(new NumberField("x₀", param.x0, 0., true)),
    Y(new NumberField("y₀", param.y0, 0., true)),
   ...
```

and thats when it complains

Comment: it would have been very useful if you had provided a simple short example that contains all necessary lines that are needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

the method that is changing x0 is a static method, correct? So it doesn't know what the object is that x0 lives in, as x0 is an instance field.

It doesn't appear you show the code that actually the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score -1):

If you use JTextArea, you won't have any problems. Just add an action listener to it, then you can add text with

```
textArea.append(String s);
```

Comment: thanks for trying to be helpful :-) Unfortunately, your answer is a bit mixed up. a) JTextArea has a append(String) method, but no api to register actionListeners b) JTextField can have actionListeners but has not method append(String).